# Plotting timeseries in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working with a time series.  The first 20 rows of my real data is shown below.  I wish to:

a. Subset my ggplot graph to a particular timeframe (e.g. only showing values between 07:46:40 and 07:49:00).

b. I also wish to change the frquency of tick marks on the x axis. Using the example detailed bwlow I want just the whole minutes to be dispalyed on the axis (however for my proper graph, I would wish just hourly values to be displayed).

Any advice on the above would be gratefully received.

```
day3 <- structure(list(Date = c("11/12/2012", "11/12/2012", "11/12/2012", 
                            "11/12/2012", "11/12/2012", "11/12/2012", "11/12/2012", "11/12/2012", 
                            "11/12/2012", "11/12/2012", "11/12/2012", "11/12/2012", "11/12/2012", 
                            "11/12/2012", "11/12/2012", "11/12/2012", "11/12/2012", "11/12/2012", 
                            "11/12/2012", "11/12/2012"), Time = c("07:46:10", "07:46:20", 
                                                                  "07:46:30", "07:46:40", "07:46:50", "07:47:00", "07:47:10", "07:47:20", 
                                                                  "07:47:30", "07:47:40", "07:47:50", "07:48:00", "07:48:10", "07:48:20", 
                                                                  "07:48:30", "07:48:40", "07:48:50", "07:49:00", "07:49:10", "07:49:20"
                            ), Axis1 = c(59L, 651L, 59L, 0L, 22L, 50L, 0L, 0L, 114L, 899L, 
                                         129L, 33L, 21L, 9L, 224L, 135L, 266L, 16L, 59L, 126L), Steps = c(1L, 
                                                                                                          2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 15L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 8L, 5L, 
                                                                                                          16L, 1L, 3L, 8L)), .Names = c("Date", "Time", "Axis1", "Steps"
                                                                                                          ), row.names = 52838:52857, class = "data.frame")
#Creates a new dataframe with a time column.
day3 <- within(day3,{
  posb <- as.POSIXlt(Time,format="%H:%M:%S")
  posb <- NULL  # cleanup
})

library(ggplot2)
g = ggplot(day3, aes(x=strptime(Time, "%H:%M:%S"), y=Axis1)) + geom_line(aes(group = 1)) +
  theme_bw() +
  xlab("Time") + 
  ylab("Activity (Counts per 10 seconds)") + 
  scale_x_datetime(limits=c(as.POSIXct("07:47:50"),as.POSIXct("07:49:10")))


g
```

**Edit**

if I wanted to add a text box onto my graph, how do I work with the time column?
So far I have got:

```
geom_text(aes(05:00,0),label="Sedentary")
```

... but this doesn't want to work at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
library(scales)
ggplot(day3, aes(x=strptime(Time, "%H:%M:%S"), y=Axis1)) + geom_line(aes(group = 1)) +
  theme_bw() +
  xlab("Time") + 
  ylab("Activity (Counts per 10 seconds)") +
  scale_x_datetime(limits=c(as.POSIXct("07:46:40",format="%H:%M:%S"),as.POSIXct("07:49:00",format="%H:%M:%S")),
                   breaks=date_breaks("1 min"), labels = date_format("%H:%M"))
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks @juba - that's great.  I have a last question regarding plotting timeseries (which I have added to my original question).  Any advice would be great!

Comment: Try  something like `geom_text(aes(x=as.POSIXct("07:48:00", format="%H:%M:%S"), y=250), label="foo")`